# Python ForLoop syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

This works:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    print "hi"
```

This doesn't work:

```
for range(0, 3):
    print "hi"
```

but I don't need the 'i' for anything at all. Is there a way to write a 'for' statement without the 'i' or a different character which assumes the same role?

( Typically, it would be something like

```
for i in range(0, someReturnValue())
    someFunction()
```

but the question is generalizable to my first examples.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need a lopping variable(index), the best practice is to use `_` (which is, really, just another variable):

```
for _ in range(0, 3):
    print "hi"
```

Also see:

- [Is it possible to implement a Python for range loop without an iterator variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818828/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-python-for-range-loop-without-an-iterator-variable)
- [pythonic way to do something N times without an index variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970780/pythonic-way-to-do-something-n-times)

Comment: Oh hey, there was a question already - didn't see that (And I did look!)

Comment: Additional question: The scope of the ' _ ' is for that loop, presumably - what if I need to do nested loops, will using ' _ ' in the internal loop mess it up for the external loop?

Comment: You shouldn't use the same variable name inside nested loops, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255455/same-variable-name-for-different-values-in-nested-loops. Turn on your imagination in that case :)

Comment: for loopOne in range(0, 3)    for loopTwo in range(0, 5)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned elsewhere, this is an interesting and possibly faster alternative:

```
import itertools

for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 3):
    print 'hi'
```