# Python nested for loop using *same* variable

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.5, scoping

Out of curiosity, I tried implementing a nested for loop using the same iterating variable in both the outer and inner for loops.

```
for i in range(3):
    for i in range(4):
        print("i = %s" % i)
```

What exactly is going on behind the scene here? BTW, the inner print is executed 12 times.

Comment: The for statement does not use `i` for looping. It just assigns current iteration value to `i` before running loop body. That's why it runs fine. The print will only show inner for's `i` values though.

Comment: The inner loop rewrites the outer `i` variable. This is fine as long as you aren't doing anything with it.

Comment: @vaultah Couldn't find a duplicate?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nope, I didn't search :)

Comment: @omu_negru Um, that's not a Python question, so that logic doesn't quite apply here. ;)

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13255455/2301450) looks fairly close

Comment: It may be another language, but it's still variable shadowing, and the way it works is the same in both languages

Comment: @vaultah I just found that one too. :) I guess it'll do for now.

Comment: @omu_negru Not really, although I agree there are similarities. In Python, each range object maintains its own current value, yielding it as it's iterated over. In the C++ code there are two scopes, in the OP's code, there's only 1 (Python) scope, there isn't an inner `i` shadowing the outer `i`, there are two independent `range` objects, with their current values both being assigned to the same `i` name.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "i" is iterating the elements in the outer loop, but then is re-set to iterate the elements in the inner loop. And so on.
The bottom line is that you're gonna print the elements of the inner loop 3 times (the size of the outer one)

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the second i [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing#Python) the first one, so the print instruction will only reffer to the inner loop i